# Logcat incorrectly says there is no such column in SQLite database - Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, logcat

At the top of this Logcat it says there is no such column where name == Ben10. However, at the bottom of this Logcat I have logged the users with thier imagePath, then id, then name, then password. Ben10a signifies the name Ben10 with password a. So there is a column where name is Ben10.

```
12-31 02:05:10.195: D/dalvikvm(1091): GREF has increased to 201
    12-31 02:05:16.105: E/dbHelper(1091): SELECT  * FROM AppUser WHERE name = Ben10
    12-31 02:05:16.105: E/SQLiteLog(1091): (1) no such column: Ben10
    12-31 02:05:16.235: D/Get database Items(1091): Getting all database items
    12-31 02:05:16.245: E/dbHelper(1091): SELECT  * FROM ClothingItem
    12-31 02:05:16.256: E/dbHelper(1091): SELECT  * FROM AppUser
    12-31 02:05:16.256: D/ClothingItem(1091): 1hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.275: D/ClothingItem(1091): 2hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.275: D/ClothingItem(1091): 3hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.275: D/ClothingItem(1091): 4hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.275: D/ClothingItem(1091): 5hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.275: D/ClothingItem(1091): 6hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.275: D/ClothingItem(1091): 7hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/ClothingItem(1091): 8hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/ClothingItem(1091): 9hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/ClothingItem(1091): 10hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/ClothingItem(1091): 11hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/ClothingItem(1091): 12hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/ClothingItem(1091): 13hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/ClothingItem(1091): 14hathat1
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/User(1091): content://media/external/images/media/121Bena
    12-31 02:05:16.285: D/User(1091): content://media/external/images/media/122Ben10a
    12-31 02:05:16.315: D/dalvikvm(1091): GC_CONCURRENT freed 140K, 2% free 12075K/12295K, paused 72ms+30ms, total 164ms
```

Comment: Ben10 is value, name is column, so no such column: Ben10 is correct

Comment: @henry4343 yeah, that's just SQLites strange log. I'm pretty sure it means no such value Ben10 in the name column.

Comment: Please post your activity code, if you are sure about this.

Comment: @henry4343 in that log, I think column means one line in the database (one entry).

Comment: What ? Column is not what you are saying, its called record..

Comment: @shree202 I will try to find the code you request. The previous comment meant `12-31 02:05:16.105: E/SQLiteLog(1091): (1) no such column: Ben10` SQLite prints that log. That is not printing because there is no column named Ben10. It would have no reason to do that. I have not asked for a column named Ben10. That is what SQLite logs when there is no entry where name == Ben10

Comment: I guess, you are working with database for the first time. when there is no record found, sqlite never logs anything. @henry4343 is correct. it only logs if any error occurs working with database.

Comment: @shree202 I never said there was no error. It is logging because there is an error. I have executed SQL "SELECT  * FROM AppUser WHERE name = Ben10" And SQLite error message to that is "(1) no such column: Ben10". I definitely do not have a column named Ben10, and do not ask for one either.

Comment: There literally is a cliche "select isn't broken".

The title is this question is amusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apostrophes for enclosing strings in sql-queries.
So try this:

```
select * from AppUser where name = 'Bem10'
```

Comment: @grennis Lol I knew Logcat was not incorrect, but after dealing with an error for a while on new years eve, unfortunately choosing a better question name sometimes gets put on the backburner. I was just thinking "they'll know what I mean". Haha.

Comment: @user2602079 The reason this question didn't get much attention is probably that you didn't provide your sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, [num, name, typ, notnull, comment] means column and below means value like [1,2,3,4,5]  or [id, ref, created, modified, name]

[image]

In your case,
Logcat show E/SQLiteLog(1091): (1) no such column: Ben10
so you need to check you SQL is correct ...

Maybe you use

```
SELECT  * FROM AppUser WHERE Ben10 = xxxxx so that will be crash
```

Comment: I'm not confused about columns. This is a log of the statement that creates my AppUser table: `12-31 02:29:22.125: D/create USER table(1158): CREATE TABLE AppUser (id integer primary key autoincrement, imagePath TEXT, name TEXT, password TEXT)
` The thing is, SQLite logs a slightly strangely worded log when it doesn't find the entry with the key:name, value:Ben10

Comment: But in your Logcat print E/SQLiteLog(1091): (1) no such column: Ben10 that it's mean you use column Ben10 to query data.Maybe you need to check your SQL syntax...

Comment: Maybe you can post your SQL syntax or your table data

Comment: Both are posted. I logged the SQL syntax in the original Logcat. I also logged the data in the database in that Logcat. The syntax is `12-31 02:29:30.679: E/dbHelper(1158): SELECT  * FROM AppUser WHERE name = Ben10`.